# Protect variables from injection

Tags: php, code-injection

I want to protect publicly editable variables from SQL injection.

Here's an example of code showing collected form variables to be updated. First idea was to protect the variables as below;

```
$val1 = $val2 = strtoupper;
$val1 = $val2 = strip_tags;
$val1 = $val2 = trim;
$val1 = $val2 = mysqli_real_escape_string;
```

The next idea is to protect the database query as below;

```
$update_customer = "update customer set val_1='$val1',val_2='$val2' where foo='$foo'"; //update values set

$update_cust = strtoupper($update_customer);
$update_cust = strip_tags($update_customer);
$update_cust = trim($update_customer);
$update_cust = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $update_customer);
$update_cust = mysqli_query($con, $update_customer); //inititate query
```

I presume using both ideas wouldn't be necessary but I'm not 100% on which I should use.

Comment: Why not just use parameterized queries? - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Would doing that negate the requirement for these steps or would they be additional?

Comment: Negate pretty much, unless you want your variables to be trimmed and uppered and stripped of HTML tags for any other reason

Comment: Okay I take the hint. This is for a basket page so it must be as protected as possible. I'll make some changes and come back. Thanks.

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: If you need help learning how to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for safe and secure queries, then you can check out [this answer that I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45514591/5827005) that demonstrates a function that I wrote that makes [Prepared Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) **easy**, **clean**, and **secure**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget all of what you are doing and look at [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) using mysqli.

All you need to do with your code above is something like the below:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE customer SET val_1=?,val_2=? WHERE foo=?");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $val1, $val2, $val3);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

The only reason you will need to do your `trim()`, `strip_tags()` or `strtoupper()` now is purely for personal preference and you can forget `mysqli_real_escape_string()` even exists.

Comment: Very helpful Peter, thank you :)

Comment: _or you can use PDO_

Comment: Yes I would advise looking at PDO too. I use it instead of mysqli in all my projects

Answer (score 2):

Seriously:

> Stop trying to use low-pollution diesel cars and switch to solar powered vehices.

Aka, use [***Parameterized Queries***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712037/what-is-parameterized-query) using either `PDO` or `MySQLi` PHP database functionality.

The above link to Parameterised queries would be a **replacement** for your code as show, you would **NOT** use `mysqli_real_escape_string`, or need to `strip_tags` unless for your own personal preference for what sort of data you want to store in the database.